# Android Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I follow [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/)  tutorials  i do everything from there . when i apply plugin

```
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
 /home/deadlydragger/AndroidStudioProjects/FirebaseExample/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  /home/deadlydragger/AndroidStudioProjects/FirebaseExample/app/google-services.json

this happen . But while i am importing same project from github it works well .Whats the issue behind this ? i place google-services.json in app directory .

Comment: File google-service.json is needed. You have to access your Firebase Console to generate one. Once you generate the file, place it in the root folder of your main module.

Comment: I already put google-service.json file inside app directory . But still happening this error .  this is my dependencies    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'    and i apply this in bottom of  grandle    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: did you paste it in project directory or in project\app directory ?

Comment: project / app directory

Comment: Could you add your full project and app level gradle files? The error you are seeing is likely that your google-services.json file is in the wrong location. From the error /home/deadlydragger/AndroidStudioProjects/FirebaseExample/app/google-services.json does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that you included the google-service:3.0.0 dependencies in **Top-level build file** not the **App-level build file** ? The dependencies is shown below:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'